# Battery Indicator Missing, Cannot Install Because No JDK 7

Tags: java, indicator, oracle

I'm really new to the whole linux deal, but I'm on a laptop and a battery gauge would be extremely helpful.  Whenever I try

`sudo apt-get install indicator-power`

it gives me:

```
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
indicator-power is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u40-0~webupd8~0) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2013-09-24 20:06:32--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u40-b43/jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving false (false)... failed: No such file or directory.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘false’
download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

@Braiam when I ran the first command to correct the repositories, and it came back with:

```
Can't rename /etc/apt/sources.list.d/iaz-battery-status-quantal.list /etc/apt     /sources.list.disable.d/iaz-battery-status-quantal.list.disable: No such file or directory
Can't rename /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-quantal.list /etc/apt/sources.list.disable.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-quantal.list.disable: No such file or directory
Can't rename /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-raring.list /etc/apt/sources.list.disable.d/webupd8team-java-raring.list.disable: No such file or directory
```

@Braiam, now when I run it with that line, after every line I enter, there is this response after everything else seems to have worked aside from these:

```
N: Ignoring file 'ubuntu-wine-ppa-quantal.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'iaz-battery-status-quantal.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-java-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ubuntu-wine-ppa-quantal.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'iaz-battery-status-quantal.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-java-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Comment: From `No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already` it appears that something additional isn't quite right. I've upvoted your question and if someone else does so, you should be able to go into the Ask Ubuntu chat room where people may help you troubleshoot step by step.

Comment: And if nobody helps here, please feel free to ask at ubuntuforums.org which is structured differently to allow a back-and-forth process to get you your solution ultimately :)

Comment: I upvoted for you also so you can chat

Comment: Try purging `indicator-power` and installing again.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you seem to have non Ubuntu (or pure debian) packages installs. In particular, for java you should really be using openjdk-7-jre, and not Oracle java.  The direction suggested by Briam (clean up the mess first) sounds like the right one, but the details may be incomplete to fully untangle the mess because there's not enough data on everything you have installed that is not from official repos.

Comment: @arielf How would I fix that?  I have also tried installing openjdk but it returned with a similar error and was unable to install.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what's exactly messed-up.  Once you run 3rd party, non-free (as in freedom), non-standard stuff like 'oracle-java7-installer' which don't play well with conventions and may modify system defaults and files, it is hard to know what effect is.  On the good side, most of the above added "errors" are only warnings you shouldn't worry about: files under /etc/apt/sources.list.d that end with '.disabled' are simply getting ignored, so that's ok. You should decide if you want 'raring' or 'quantal', and clean that up 1st. You can't have them both, like Braiam said. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you got some mixed repositories. Do this:

```
sudo rename -n 's/\.list$/.list.disable/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f remove oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

The first line disable any repository that aren't the official, the second updates the package list, the fourth tries to repair any error, the final install the package.

Comment: I ran the first line, and there was an issue.  I have posted the response above.

Comment: Alright, I tried with the line correction and still no luck.  Again, the results have been posted.  Thanks for taking the time to help me figure this out by the way.  Also, sudo apt-get check gives the same results as my newest edit on the original post.

Comment: I entered it and it didnt come back blank.  Posted results

Comment: Alright, tried that but something was wrong.  Is it right for us to continue responding to one another in the comments like this?  Not only am I new to Ubuntu, but these forums as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10791/discussion-between-braiam-and-zack-souza)

Answer (score -2):

To install oracle java SDK 7 just search for it in the software center and install it.  If you need to download any other softwares in the future you should check the software center they have a lot of options.